# How to manually stop R while running code wrapped in try()?

Tags: r, try-catch, rstudio, httr

I retrieve data from a server using {httr} in a for loop; sometimes requests time out, which causes an error. Since I want R to continue after errors, I wrapped this function call into try(). However, this makes it impossible for me to stop R manually using the stop button in Rstudio: {httr} throws an error and the for loop continues to the next iteration.

What can I do to ensure R stops when I hit 'stop' in Rstudio?

## example code:

```
require(httr)

authorlist<-c("alice","bob","charlie","david","erin","frank")
datalist<-list()
for(author in authorlist){
    result<-NULL
    count<-0
    while(is.null(result) & count<5){
        try(
          result<-GET(paste0("https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/comment?author=",author),timeout(10))
        )
    }
    datalist[length(datalist)+1]<-result
}
```

I expect R to stop processing; but it merely skips to the next loop iteration (of either for-loop).

Comment: take a look at: https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/safely.html

Comment: Thank you! That does the job.